# Appium: getting stuck at tapping on buttons under a loop

Tags: appium

I am getting stuck at executing a loop. My scenario is:  I am tapping on bookmark present over the screen.

I am using below code for that ,

```
  List listAllSessionsNames=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[*]//descendant::UIAButton"));

  for(MobileElement eachSessionName:listAllSessionsNames)  {
    try{
      if(!eachSessionName.isDisplayed()){

         // initIPHONE.swipeDown();
          eachSessionName.click();   
      }

      else{
          initIPHONE.swipeDown(); 

          eachSessionName.click();    
      }

    }

    catch(WebDriverException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }     
  }
```

The problem is that the button is getting tapped until buttons are visible on screen but getting `webdriverexception` after tapping on the same button.
The whole size of the table cell over the screen is 10 but this code can work for 5.
Please help.

Comment: Q1- What exception are you getting. Q-2 :Clear the last line (regarding the 10, 5). That is confusing.

Comment: i am getting WebDriverException .but this issue is resolved to some extent by re assigning the list after swipe .
Currently after first swipe ,buttons are tapped multiple times that is weird .

Comment: Then update you question with the latest information. That would be good

Comment: What is returns when you print `listAllSessionsNames.size()` ?

Comment: It was returned me exact no of values and that was 10.